# Windows software install automation

Tags: batch-file, autoit

I am trying to automate the task of installing a software on Windows 7 and its an .exe file which requires user input in the form of `Next` or `Ok`. I have to first push that .exe (WinampInstall.exe) file on to the machines (over 100 of them). Additionally it should run silently without requiring any input from the user.

Until now I have come across AutoIt which can create macros which can replay the actions of the mouse and keyboard. I'm having trouble with the .au3 script, as it doesn't fully automate the installation.

Can I use batch file to run the script as well?

```
Run('C:\Users\Desktop\WinampInstall.exe')
_WinWaitActivate("SciTE","Address: C:\Program ")
MouseMove(630,19)
MouseDown("left")
MouseMove(609,-150)
MouseUp("left")
MouseMove(301,9)
MouseDown("left")
MouseMove(578,-18)
MouseUp("left")
```

Comment: is what you want in https://chocolatey.org/  if so, use that

Comment: Batch can't interact with GUIs, but an easier way to do this is to use the /S option to install silently.

Comment: @KeithNicholas I believe chocolatey requires internet on the machines on which we are trying to download the .exe file ? what if we don't have access to internet and we have manually push the .exe file on to the machines and then use chocolatey ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [WinAmp forums](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=219798), you can use command line switches with the installer.

> winamp50*.exe /S /install=SFQDRA
>   
>   **/S** = Silent install
>   **S**  = start menu icons
>   **F**  = file association
>   **Q**  = quicklaunch icon
>   **D**  = desktop icon
>   **R**  = fake registration
>   **A**  = run winamp agent/set default

An example batch-file using command-line switches that would

1. Copy the `WinAmp` installer from a network share
2. Install `WinAmp` silently (using the `/s` switch)

```
@echo off
set "localPath=%temp%\WinampInstall.exe"
copy "\\network-share\WinampInstall.exe" "%localPath%"
"%localPath%" /S
pause
```